# Redis does not retrieve all data from database

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

While retrieve the values of the keys I have added on Redis Server with C#, all data is not retrieve.

For example I have key 192.168.1.1 and value of this key A$B$C$D$E$F$G$H with delimitter $ for split.

When i try to retrieve value of 192.168.1.1 from Redis with this c# code;

```
    public string GetCurrentVersion(string clientName)
    {
        return PipelineGet(redis.GetDatabase().StringGetAsync(clientName + ",Plugins"));
    }

    private string PipelineGet(Task<RedisValue> value)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = redis.GetRedis().Wait(value);
            if (result.ToString() == null)
            {
                return "";
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

It returns values of 192.168.1.1 like ABCD or ABCDE or AB or ABCDEEFGH. Sometimes retrieve all data but sometimes not. Not waiting for all data to be retrieved stable. Can someone explain this reason please?

Here is the insert function;

```
    public void InsertCurrentVersion(string clientName, string pluginName, string currentVersion)
    {
        redis.GetDatabase().StringAppend(clientName + ",Plugins", pluginName + "," + currentVersion + "$");
    }
```

Comment: This seems highly unlikely; I'm happy to consider that something is wrong, but: how are you *writing* this value? is it perhaps possible (and more likely?) that you're seeing an intermediate state from something that is *writing* it as multiple calls to `APPEND`? Note: there's no need to use `StringGetAsync` here - `StringGet` should work fine, but: either way, the value should be immutable, so I don't think that should matter.

Comment: to emphasize: I'm not saying it *isn't* a library bug, but... it seems that it would be a good idea to rule out a more likely cause first (i.e. `APPEND`) (also: what library version, what target framework, etc)

Comment: @MarcGravell i added append function too. Latest Redis version 2.6.1 and 4.8 .Net framework version

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edit that shows usage of `StringAppend`, it seems like you're simply seeing intermediate values as they are at the instant you query, especially when dealing with multiple threads or multiple nodes. Ultimately if one code-path is building up the value via `APPEND` and another code-path queries the value *in between two appends*, then the value is *whatever it is at that time*. If you were to run `MONITOR`, you'd probably see something like:

```
DEL 192.168.1.1
APPEND 192.168.1.1 A$
APPEND 192.168.1.1 B$
GET 192.168.1.1
APPEND 192.168.1.1 C$
APPEND 192.168.1.1 D$
```

in which case yes, the value from the `GET` is going to be `A$B$`, because *that's what the value is at that time*.

If you want atomicity, then that's something your code needs to provide; there are multiple ways of doing that, including:

1. concatenate the values *in your code*, then issue a single call to `StringSet` (this is ideal for small values like this)
2. use `MULTI`/`EXEC` (i.e. `CreateTransaction()` in StackExchange.Redis) to create an atomic block of operations (not sure this makes much sense in this context, but can be useful in other scenarios)
3. write the values to a *different, temporary* key while you are building it, and then use `RENAME` (`KeyRename()` in StackExchange.Redis) to swap the keys atomically
4. perform a block of operations server-side in Lua via `EVAL` (`ScriptEvaluate()` in StackExchange.Redis) - again, probably not relevant *to this specific scenario*

I'd go with option 1 myself.

Comment: Get function is waiting for the ok message to be broadcast on the redis channel to execute. When the Insert function is completed, ok message is broadcast to the redis channel. When I monitored with redis-cli.exe, I analyze that there was no concurrency i think.

Comment: @Heisenberg k, but: what you're describing would fit *exactly* with this kind of `APPEND` timing error, so: that seems the most likely culprit - it seems unlikely (not impossible, but unlikely) that you've found a scenario where the library somehow reads the wrong number of bytes *and doesn't notice* (these are bulk-strings in RESP terms, so the payload length is prefixed - it doesn't even need to do any thinking here). Do you have any kind of reproducible demo I can look at? additional thought: are you perhaps querying from replicas that might be a few milliseconds (or more) behind?

Comment: When i test few times, i saw there was concurrency problem. Channel messages broadcast wrong time. Thank you!